# Relative merits of proofs of the Borel–Cantelli lemma

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics

The first Borel–Cantelli lemma says:

> Suppose $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \Pr( A_k)<\infty.$$ Then $$\Pr(\text{infinitely many of } A_1,A_2,A_3,\ldots \text{ are true}) =0.$$

A frequently seen argument goes like this:

\begin{align}
& \text{For each } n\in\{1,2,3,\ldots\}, \\[3pt]
& \Pr(\text{infinitely many are true}) \\[6pt]
\le {} & \Pr(A_n \text{ or } A_{n+1} \text{ or } A_{n+1} \text{ or } \cdots{}) \\
& \qquad \text{(inclusive “or'')} \\[6pt]
\le {} & \sum_{k\,=\,n}^\infty \Pr(A_k) \to 0 \text{ as } n\to\infty
\end{align}
Now, where we have
$$
\Pr(\infty\text{-many}) \le \sum_{k\,=\,n}^\infty\cdots, \tag 1
$$
**the number on the left side of $(1)$ does not change as 
$n\to\infty$.**

(That last line, set in **bold** is something one would usually omit if writing for mathematicians, and is an example of the sort of thing about which one should more often be explicit when writing for students.)

Another proof says the **expected** number of propositions $A_1,A_2,A_3,\ldots$ that are true is
$$
\sum_{k\,=\,1}^\infty \Pr(A_k) < \infty
$$
and that could not be the case if $\Pr(\infty\text{-many})>0.$

What reasons are there to prefer one or the other of these arguments?

Answer (score 3):

I think the differences can be surmised as "combinatoric" vs "analytic" respectively.

The first proof uses considerably less machinery than the second, and it also potentially skirts the clunky definition of infinitely-often as: $\bigcap_{N=1}^\infty \bigcup_{k=N}^\infty A_k$ (e.g, the first inequality becomes an equality if you take an infimum over $n$). So if teaching to less-experienced students, this proof seems preferable.

For the expected value proof, you need the monotone convergence theorem and even some basic measure theory. However, it introduces a nice duality between sets occurring infinitely often and functions being integrable. Such expectation "tricks" can be really valuable to know. For example, proving the inclusion-exclusion principle by expanding the right side of $P(A_1^c\cap\cdots \cap A_n^c) = E\left[\prod_{i=1}^n(1-1_{A_k})\right]$.

Comment: That the sum of the expectations equals the expectation of the sum even when there are infinitely many terms may appear to be needed here. But I'm not sure one needs the full strength of that proposition for this special case. And many students would never notice such a question, and in some pedagogical contexts one sweeps such questions under the carpet simply by not mentioning them. If you mean the first proof is easier to make fully rigorous, then it seems you're right.